# How many hamsters power the StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, fun

According to Nick Craver, [hamsters power StackOverflow and related sites](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/84422403660324864).  At any given time, how many run the site?  What is the average turnover (how often do they need to be replaced)?

Comment: What is their caloric output?

Comment: It hasn't been Friday in Iceland in quite a long time...

Comment: Are there any hamsters that hold a position of command? Or are they the subordinates of a larger mammels?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

We use 932 hampsters in rotating shifts of 212 for the web tier, they get 3 weeks of vacation time and all the carrots they want.  Benefits also include medical and time off every 4th Tuesday and a bathroom break every 36 hours - we treat the help quite well here.

Comment: Why do I hear the cracking of whips and smell a faint whiff of ozone?

Comment: @jcolebrand - these aren't the hamsters you're looking for

Comment: They'll be breeding like the clappers. You done a headcount recently?

Comment: @Mr. - how do you think we replace the old ones?

Comment: @Nick, I can see a technical difficulty with this approach: being *crepuscular*, how are they kept active during non-twilight hours? Are they treated like battery hens with artificial lighting? I think we'd all prefer you use free-range hamsters..

Comment: You guys could be a lot more efficient if you upgraded to these human sized ones: http://bit.ly/ieyD1f

Comment: What is that strange number `932`? It isn't a power of two, it confuses me. Also if you said *we use 0x03A4 hamsters* then i would understand a lot better.

Comment: Curious. Do you store power in preparation for the 4th Tuesday?

Comment: Don't be daft, @Xaade. They _obviously_ stagger the Tuesdays across four groups of hamsters, so we only see a 25% power loss on any given Tuesday.

Answer (score 49):

Each hamster consumes about 400 calories a day, which is just under 1/2 watt/day, or 12 watt hours.  Assuming a 50% fuel to energy conversion (pretty optimistic, but let's assume these are elite hamsters that prefer the hamster wheel to running about the cage) then we can get about 6 watt hours out of an active hamster, on average, each day.  The motor in the hamster cage is, sadly, only about 80% efficient, and the DC/DC converter to the power buss bars is a nice efficient 90%, but then we have to upconvert the DC buss once more before powering the data center, and that sucker only runs at 80% efficiency.  So we only end up with 3.5WH/day out of each hamster.

Each server consumes about 600 watts per hour, and [there are about 18 servers](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/09/30/the-stack-exchange-architecture-2011-edition-episode-1/), so we're running about 11KW, which is 264KW hours per day.

So, excluding HVAC power, lights, infrastructure, and other overhead costs, Stack Exchange must be running at least 76,000 hamsters.

Hamsters have a MTBF of about 20 months which means that they have to replace about 125 hamsters per day - about one every twelve minutes.  This system, unlike feeding and cage cleaning, is not automated, so they probably have two or more hamster technicians on 24/7 call to handle this and a few other relevant duties.

Of course this doesn't count hamsters on disability, medical, vacation, or maternity leave, which may require another 50-70 thousand hamsters. Further, I'm generalizing on power requirements - with peak usage energy storage, sane power schemes, and other techniques they could be easily using half this required power on average.

That may seem like a lot of Hamsters, but you have to realize that Stack Exchange is handling 95 million page hits per month - so each hamster is powering 41 page hits a day.  Even though Google employs more pigeons, I suspect that Stack Exchange is more efficient on an animals-per-page-served basis.

I dare you to teach a hamster to serve 41 pages a year, nevermind each day.

Comment: And boy is PETA *pissed*...

Comment: "600 watts per hour"?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest firing the chaos monkey.

Seems like in between flinging poo he's also unplugging the servers.