# We are offline ... we will post details on the blog and twitter

Tags: feature-request, fun, humor

*Note, this is semi-serious, mainly due to the fact the blogs were down and my imagination wasn't... It's also possible this is already the case, just not linked in the maintenance message. Mod-closed? Extreme downvoting? Meh, and meh.*

---

Post updates on outages on *#twitter* as well as (some apparently *future*) postmortem blog entry:

> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns
>   into an extended outage, we will post details on the blog *and **twitter***.

Because we're so interested in knowing what's *really* going on... in *realtime*...

> **#stackeasy**: Just brought all SE sites down. Last minute always #sukx,
>   but preemptive strikes are #kewl.
>
> **#stackeasy**: Just gotta get in there and reload that (breaking) #phlugerphlarg before it #overfloods. Shutting down...
>
> **#stackeasy**: This is gonna be easy. Shutdown and rebuilding, maybe
>   I'll get some coffee from #starducks.
>
> **#stackeasy**: What the! DB host is sharding itself, abort abort!
>
> **#stackeasy**: This coffee is terrible.
>
> **#stackeasy**: All sites down now without warning (well, not much of
>   one) for over an hour. Rebuilding again.
>
> **#stackeasy**: Anybody know a good Chinese place in #Sasketchewan (sp?)?
>
> **#stackeasy**: Good thing we kept that restore point...
>
> **#stackeasy**: Bringing back #metaso, the crybabies.
>
> **#stackeasy**: Alright, so that came up. Now one at a time.
>
> **#stackeasy**: But what the
>
> **#stackeasy**: all yer citez blong to us
>
> **#stackeasy**: intertoobz are for boobz
>
> **#stackeasy**: lolz lolz needz moor kowbel
>
> **#stackeasy**: localhost is #publicmine!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> **#stackeasy**: That was #soweird. Ok, should be restarting 800 lb
>   gorilla in 5, 4, 3, 2 ...
>
> **#stackeasy**: Ok, anybody know how to restart this thing? I keep
>   getting errors. Just reply to #stackeasy with codez, plz.

Comment: A live stream of the server room would be entertaining to watch. :)

Comment: The fact that an error occurred, and that the error reporting process (blog) was equally broken reminds me of this problem: [What happens when there's insufficient memory to throw an OutOfMemoryError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261705/what-happens-when-theres-insufficient-memory-to-throw-an-outofmemoryerror) Dear Stack Exchange, communication is key!

Comment: @TomWijsman if you can guess the name of our google hangout ...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Live-blogging? What is this, 2010? We need a publicly broadcast video conference, containing at least the following:

- Kyle, in his office, shouting at Geoff via Skype, "No no no, the Ethernet cable is the one that looks like a phone cable, just with a bigger plug!"
- Geoff, in the datacenter in Oregon, with one hand trying to keep the rack from falling over, while with the other one feeding the hamsters. He has a screwdriver between his teeth, attempting to push the server's power button with it.
- Marc, in England, franatically coding a Powershell script that reenables the air conditoning in the colo. He'll later switch to manually writing IL instead.
- Nick, at home, preparing his overpowered dev PC to take over the duty as both web and DB server for Stack Overflow during the downtime.
- Me, in Berlin, trying to hide my  German accent while doing the live commenting of the whole situation. In Markdown, of course.
- Sam, in Australia, yelling at all of us that we're not fast enough.
- Jeff, in California, showing the twins on his 64-inch secondary monitor what happens as soon as daddy leaves those crazy guys on their own.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What, no [telepresence](http://www.cisco.com/web/telepresence/video-conferencing.html) in [rotoscoped 3D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxcI7Nf_DsY)?

Comment: You really shouldn't have used regex for the [automated hamster feeding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114661/2915).

Comment: I'm willing to make random Meta commentary from the sidelines, if it helps.

Comment: I guess you forgot Rebecca going oy at Sam, then keeping Jeff's babies at bay with her backwards smile?

Comment: Joel asking everyone repeatedly what little thing about outages and downtime catch you off guard or make you smile.

Comment: actually you made this sound kinda awesome. I am not sure that was your intent...

Comment: And you writing all this stuff... :)