# What does the last "rev" number mean?

Tags: support

I am referring to the thing at the bottom-right of every SE page. Clearly, the first three numbers are YYYY.M.DD, but I can't figure out what the last number is.

[image: "rev 2012.2.21.1163"]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That number is how many [hamsters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96356/140548) we have.  As you can see if you watch the number over a period of time, they breed like crazy.

Alternatively, it's the number of dev builds we've had on our Team City build server.

Comment: See, now if you would upgrade to trained guinea pigs you wouldn't need so many.

Comment: Hmm... but how do you count them all before they move and you lose track of which ones you've counted?

Comment: Really? Wow! How do you manage to keep your hamster count and build count synchronized at all times?

Comment: @PopularDemand I'm pretty sure via the application of electricity. They shock them.