# My question votes have wandered off

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, voting, profile-page

I had misplaced some **question votes** the other day, and I've been looking all over for them.  With all these new-fangled reputation changes happening here on meta, I decided to take a peek at my reputation tab, to observe it's renewed glory and splendor.  You won't believe what I found!

[image]

**My question votes!**  Lo and behold, they had meandered over to the *reputation tab*.  Needless to say, I was surprised to see them there, since they don't affect my reputation =P

---

Ok, seriously though.  The circled items are for downvotes I cast on questions (notice the lack of a "-1" next to them).  The uncircled ones are for downvotes on answers.  I can *completely* understand the downvotes on answers showing up.

But voting on questions doesn't affect your reputation at all, so I think that **votes on questions should not show up in the reputation tab.** (<---*I've tagged this as a bug, because this seems like unexpected behavior.  But, if it's by-design, this could be a feature request*)

Questions?  Comments?  Snide remarks?

<sub>waffles?</sub>

Comment: Well, the "responses" tab also shows when people have edited your content, so... "log of vote-related activity" is a bit wordy to put on the tab, I think.

Comment: @TimStone I hadn't really thought about it that way.  I think having edits show up under "responses" makes some sense.  Someone "responded" to your post by editing it (*ok, I guess that's kind of a stretch*).

Comment: Where exactly should they show up? Where would you be most likely to go looking for them, other than with *all of the other* votes you've cast?

Comment: @CodyGray It's not a list of all the votes I've cast.  My *upvotes* on questions and answers don't show up on that tab.  My answer downvotes show up because they affect reputation.  I think question downvotes should fall in with the upvotes (inapplicable on the reputation tab).

Comment: Well, I know why they're there. They are there because that information appears in the query that generates the data for reputation (just with zero values). Banishing them because they don't affect your reputation means that, for completeness, the SE devs would have to write another query and web page, just to accomodate the votes that don't affect reputation and make you feel less itchy. Don't they have enough [hamsters running already?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96354/how-many-hamsters-power-the-stackexchange-sites)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent of the reputation page it to show changes or potential changes (over-votes once capped).  Since question downvotes or reverals of those have *zero* chance of doing this, they'll be hidden after the next build.

Comment: You rock!  I hope you all know we appreciate all the attention this has been getting while you roll it out.  Keep up the great work =)