# Chat is currently down

Tags: support

So, I tried to get into chat today only to get a connection timeout.

I figured it might be my connection, but [isup.me](http://www.isup.me/chat.stackexchange.com) is also saying that chat.stackexchange.com is down:
[image: isup page for chat.stackexchange.com with freehand circle].

(Note: I added a freehand circle because those are mandatory on Meta.)

Comment: I should probably note that I was following a link from my inbox to chat, so there's not really a chance I got the wrong domain by accident.

Comment: Yeah. It's down for me, too. I was in chat when it happened.

Comment: +1 for "Note: I added a freehand circle because those are mandatory on Meta."

Comment: BTW, I was in two chats when it happened.

Comment: All three chat-servers (chat.so, chat.se, chat.meta.se) are currently down from what I can see

Comment: ["We are aware of the chat issue - we are working on bringing the chat load balancer online now."](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/588331610304557057)

Comment: maybe adding an answer for that was overkill...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Good.  I checked StackStatus's twitter before posting this, their last post at that point was from a few days ago.

Comment: Chat is back on, so it seems.

Comment: @MARamezani In that case, I'm voting to close my own question as off-topic, no longer reproducible.

Comment: Good call @Powerlord, but you might wait for one of the SE guys to explain this a little bit. Maybe we'll see such failures in the future?

Comment: @MARamezani diamond gives the ability to answer even a closed question, so that won't stop them from posting such explanation. Ninja edit: such a diamond just put the final closing seal on the question. :)

Comment: @Shadow I think they'll be explaining this in six to eight weeks.

Comment: @MARamezani well, they posted on twitter - "flogged the lazy hamsters and issued demerits accordingly" sounds like a reasonable explanation... :D

Answer (score 2):

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/588336225850888192

> Chat is back online - we have flogged the lazy hamsters and issued demerits accordingly.

Comment: Hamster architecture: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96354/how-many-hamsters-power-the-stackexchange-sites/114661#114661